# When user linux docker image no issues, but windows docker image fails

Tags: docker, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I get the following error when using windows docker golang image...

> Job failed: Error response from daemon: manifest for
>   golang:latest-windowsservercore-1803 not found

line from .gitlab-ciyml file...

> image: golang:latest-windowsservercore

However, when I use the default golang image which is based on linux i think, it works fine with no errors.

the below works...

> image: golang:latest

I need the build phase to build windows executable;le hence the change.  I have tried lots of different permutations take from...

https://hub.docker.com/_/golang

but nothing works is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: This image is based on Windows Server Core (microsoft/windowsservercore). As such, it only works in places which that image does, such as Windows 10 Professional/Enterprise (Anniversary Edition) or Windows Server 2016... From docker hub

Comment: so is that because gitlab does not support the image?

Comment: yes seem like that the offical message of Microsoft mentioned "Your host must have the Windows container feature enabled. The Windows container feature is only available on Windows Server 2016 (Core and with Desktop Experience), Windows 10 Professional and Enterprise (Anniversary Edition) and later."

Comment: ok thanks, looking a container registry seems I may be able to enable it.

Comment: you check the combination table, you will get the answer from combination table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This image is based on Windows Server Core
>   (microsoft/windowsservercore). As such, it only works in places which
>   that image does, such as Windows 10 Professional/Enterprise
>   (Anniversary Edition) or Windows Server 2016.

[golang-dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang)

So if you using gitlib then there is also some limitation and combination of the container.

**The Docker executor**

> GitLab Runner can use Docker to run jobs on user provided images. This
>   is possible with the use of Docker executor.
>
> The Docker executor when used with GitLab CI, connects to Docker
>   Engine and runs each build in a separate and isolated container using
>   the predefined image that is set up in .gitlab-ci.yml and in
>   accordance in config.toml.

The following table lists what combinations of containers, executors, and OS are supported.

[image]

[docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)

You can check also window container limitation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#limitations)